# How to plot the Google QuickDraw Dataset in Python?

Tags: python, json, quickdraw

I have extracted the strokes data from the QuickDraw Dataset (JSON format), but I have no idea on how to plot it in Python. I tried several times, but doesn't work at all. I need help on plotting the strokes in Python. The following is my code for extraction strokes data:

```
import json
file = open(filepath)
lines = file.readlines()

data = json.loads(lines[0])
strokes = data['drawing']
x = strokes[0][0]
y = strokes[0][1]
```

The following text is the first line of the datafile:

```
{"word":"airplane","countrycode":"US","timestamp":"2017-03-08 21:12:07.26604      UTC","recognized":true,"key_id":"5152802093400064","drawing":[[[167,109,80,69,58,31,57,117,99,52,30,6,1,2,66,98,253,254,246,182,165],[140,194,227,232,229,229,206,124,123,149,157,159,153,110,82,77,74,109,121,127,120]],[[207,207,210,221,238],[74,103,114,128,135]],[[119,107,76,70,49,39,60,93],[72,41,3,0,1,5,38,70]]]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Swati's answer, there's a [`quickdraw` python package](https://quickdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that makes this easy:

```
from quickdraw import QuickDrawData

qd = QuickDrawData()

anvil = qd.get_drawing("anvil")
anvil.image.show()
```

If you want to do it manually, you can `zip()` the all the x values and the y values and render that (using PIL or anything else):

```
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# read ndjson lines
lines = open('full_simplified_cat.ndjson','r').readlines()
# grab the first line, JSON parse it and fetch the 'drawing' array
raw_drawing = json.loads(lines[0])['drawing']

print('before',raw_drawing)
# zip x,y coordinates for each point in every polyline
polylines = (zip(polyline[0], polyline[1]) for polyline in raw_drawing)
# notice how the data is shuffled to (x1,y1),(x2,y2) order
print('after',polylines)

# make a new image
pil_img = Image.new("RGB", (240, 270), (255,255,255))
# get a drawing context
d = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_img)
# render each polyline
for polyline in polylines:
    d.line(polyline,fill=(0, 0, 0),width=3)
# display image
pil_img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://colab.research.google.com/github/zaidalyafeai/Notebooks/blob/master/QuickDraw10.ipynb#scrollTo=Rxktd50yL-Za

It contains all the preprocessing of data, training, and testing of data.